# Convert double to int and keep decimals

Tags: c++

How would be efficient way to convert double to int (by only removing decimal symbol and adding 0-5 zeroes after decimal) like examples below?

```
Examples: 
double / int
0.55 / 55000
0.2 / 20000
1.55 / 155000
1.4523 / 145230
```

Comment: Multiply your double by a  power of 10, like 1000000. `int i = static_cast<int>(x*1000000.0);` What you are trying to do is store a whole number of millionths.

Comment: Search the internet for "fixed point math"

Comment: Not the most "efficient", but certainly "easiest" is to write the floating point into a string with whatever precision you desire, and then parse the string, generate a new string without a decimal place, append however many zeros you want, then try to parse said string into an integer format.